# Notepad++ set custom zoom

Tags: notepad++, text-editors

How can I set custom zoom in Notepad++? I want to set it to 90 or 110. The reason I want to do is I use Consolas and font size 10 is too small and 11 is too big.

Comment: Did you try the various Ctrl+mousewheel zoom levels?

Comment: @Karan Yes I have tried that option but it doesn't do what I am looking for. And why did you delete my other question. I would like to know about other text editors that support this option. This is what I see as mentioned by you "Deleted off-topic software rec portion"

Comment: Software recommendation questions are off-topic and would have got your entire question closed. Since part of it was on-topic I let that be to prevent this from happening. If you want alternatives ask on http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: Did you try setting the font size to 10.5? I think Windows supports fractional values.

Answer (score 1):

The zooming functionality in Notepad++ actually works via changing the point size not by a 'custom' zooming display feature (ie. it's no different than you changing the font size).

Taken from [Scintilla documentation](http://www.scintilla.org/ScintillaDoc.html#Zooming) (Notepad++ is based on Scintilla):

> Scintilla incorporates a "zoom factor" that lets you make all the text
>   in the document larger or smaller in steps of one point. The displayed
>   point size never goes below 2, whatever zoom factor you set. You can
>   set zoom factors in the range -10 to +20 points.